# Current input value does not get passed to event handler in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in groups">
    <td hidden><input type="hidden" value="{{item.id_group}}" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="{{item.description}}" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td>
        <a href="" ng-click="editGroup(item)">Edit |</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="deleteGroup(item)">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So this code was supposed to show values in a table and when the user changes anything in the description and click on Edit, it should POST the new value to the server. Instead it's posting the old value, I need some help please to identify why this is happening.

Comment: You should really be using buttons for those actions. Anchors are for navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Ng-model

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in groups track by $index">
    <td hidden><input type="hidden"  ng-model="groups[$index].id_group" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="groups[$index].description" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td>
        <a href="" ng-click="editGroup(item)">Edit |</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="deleteGroup(item)">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```